# I cannot move images using UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT Keys, because of buttons

Tags: image, delphi, button, key, move

I have made an application form in which I put 1 image and 4 buttons. Whenever I press the keys: up, down, left, right, to move the image, it selects me the buttons, insteed of moving the image. For example, if I press the down key, it will select me the button2, if I press up, it will select me the button1....

I am sorry, I cannot really describe it how exactly it looks like, try it at your form and you will see what I mean, the code is this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_UP:
      image1.Top := image1.Top - 10;
    VK_DOWN:
      image1.Top := image1.Top + 10;
    VK_LEFT:
      image1.Left := image1.Left - 10;
    VK_RIGHT:
      image1.Left := image1.Left + 10;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Use buttons (and all other controls) that can't get focus, like `TSpeedButton` for instance.

Comment: @LURD: That doesn't matter.

Comment: See [`Delphi XE and Trapping Arrow Key with OnKeyDown`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8620703/576719).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, yes I realized that, removed comment and added possible duplicate.

Comment: @LURD: I don't think it is a perfect duplicate, because the best solution in this case isn't to actually trap the arrow keys, but to put the image in a separate control.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, question is a bit unclear. Does the OP want to know why the arrow keys is moving the selection instead of the image, or a solution how to move the image with arrow keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution is to put your control (the image) into a window (control) that handles the dialog keys, and then to make sure that this control receives keyboard focus at the appropriate times.

Well, honestly, you seem to draw/animate things by moving graphic controls. The *very* best way is to create a custom control (descending from `TCustomControl`) and draw things manually (or, possibly, to have graphic child controls). Then you can easily make this control respond to the arrow keys.

This control does it:

```
unit WindowContainer;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Messages, Classes, Controls;

type
  TWindowContainer = class(TCustomControl)
  private
  protected
    procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property OnStartDrag;
    property OnStartDock;
    property OnUnDock;
    property OnClick;
    property OnCanResize;
    property OnAlignPosition;
    property OnAlignInsertBefore;
    property OnResize;
    property OnMouseWheel;
    property OnMouseWheelDown;
    property OnMouseWheelUp;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseLeave;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseActivate;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyDown;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TWindowContainer]);
end;

{ TWindowContainer }

constructor TWindowContainer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle := [csAcceptsControls, csCaptureMouse, csClickEvents,
    csSetCaption, csDoubleClicks, csReplicatable, csPannable,
    csFramed];
end;

procedure TWindowContainer.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTCHARS or DLGC_WANTARROWS
    or DLGC_WANTTAB or DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot]

[Sample demo EXE](https://privat.rejbrand.se/WindowContainerSample.exe)

To try this control, simply put the shape/image in it, and use the `OnKeyDown` event of this control. Also, make sure to set focus to this control, e.g. when the user clicks it:

```
procedure TForm1.WindowContainer1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WindowContainer1.SetFocus;
end;
```

Now, doing animations by moving controls is bad. Instead, you should draw manually. Combine this answer with the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224075/282848) answer and you're done.

Comment: "into a windows (control), excuse me, but what's control and which control receives keyboard focus?

Comment: @user2296565: You can easily write such a control yourself.

Comment: Could you please make me an example? Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to use `Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;` in `WM_GETDLGCODE` message handler ? Isn't `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` code an internal combination of the other key related codes (something like `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS = DLGC_WANTARROWS || DLGC_WANTCHARS || DLGC_WANTTAB`) ? [+1]

Comment: @TLama: IIRC that is *not* (surprisingly) the case.